# Search Engine of Open Cart

Tags: php, opencart

Can anyone Please tell me how the search engine of the Open Cart works. I mean to say where is the code for the search in Open Cart. Which database tables are uses to search any query?

Comment: You should accept an answer that helped You by clicking the tick underneath the answer's up/down vote buttons.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCart Search Form submits to `route=product/search` i.e. `catalog/controller/product/search.php`. This file calculates results based on submitted keywords and then loads product/search.tpl template to display search results.

Search results are generated by the controller using `catalog/product` model's `getProducts()` function. The same function used for generating ordinary product lists.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCart uses a basic search (just matches any keywords in your search), though there are other search methods available in the extension store. The tables it uses in the default are the `product` and the `product_description` tables

Answer (score 1):

Open-cart search in the category levels according your filters join with    category_description table and the products titles join the product_description Table all this according the current user Language

you Can find this code in Product Model
\catalog\model\catalog\product.php

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
```